# Storing strings in different variables

Tags: python, string, variables

I want to store strings in different variables. Below is the code which provides a powerset of strings from given symbols.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, chain

def powerset(iterable):                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

symbols = ['KEL','BYCO']
combinations = list(powerset(symbols))
del combinations[0]
my_list = combinations
```

my_list contains a list of strings as follows.

```
[('KEL',), ('BYCO',), ('KEL', 'BYCO')]
```

I want the element on 0th position to be like`symbol_0 = ('KEL')`.
To make sufficent amount of variables to incorporate the whole list I've used the following code.

```
for i in range(0,list_len):
    symbol_i = 0
    pass
print(symbol_0)
```

I expected the above code to make 3 variables namely symbol_0, symbol_1 and symbol_2. I don't get why when I print symbol_0, I get an error symbol_0 is not defined.

Comment: `symbol_0 = ('KEL')` or `symbol_0 = ('KEL',)`? In other words tuple or not?

Comment: You really don't want to create variables like this, though possible, it's neither optimal nor smart.

Comment: I want symbol_0 = ('KEL')

Comment: The reason why Python does not make `symbol_0` is because it sees `symbol_i` as the full name. It does not do an analysis whether `symbol` or `i` are defined somewhere. For Python `symbol_i` is **just an identifier** (as is with almost **any** language).

Comment: But, as Dylan already says: it is **very bad design** to construct variables like that.

Comment: Given the fact that python sees it as symbol_i. How can I make several variables, since I can't start variable with a number.

Comment: Why not use a list? `symbol_i` becomes `symbol[i]`.

Comment: @FurqanHashim You should use a list or dict to store multiples, rather than differently named variables.

Comment: Can you suggest any better idea so that I can give a thought process to it.

Comment: @DylanLawrence thanks for the suggestion. I will look into dict and list.